# Magento 2 catalog search full text reindex problem

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, indexing

I'm facing strange issue in my website. The products are not getting appeared if I reindex only flat and product related reindex. It requires catalogsearch_fulltext reindex. If I dont do catalog search full text reindex products are not getting appeared in frontend.

I'm having 3 stores in my website. So it takes almost 8 hours per store to complete the full text reindex. So to bring one product in my website I have to wait for 24 hours.

How can I resolve this issue? How to bring the product without reindexing catalog search fulltext?

FYI: I'm using elastic search, Magento EE v2.1.7

Comment: Time to reindex products is directly proportional to number of product and categories in the store. It is likely you have large number of product and categories

Comment: Yes. Im having huge catalog. Almost 70k products. It may grow upto 100k. Here problem is product is not appearing without doing catalog search full text reindex.

Comment: you can do the reindex by setting cron and run at the period of time may be your emergency fix.

Comment: @Kavithamano I have setup cron job for reindexing. To launch one product in my website its became mandatory to run this reindex which takes 24 to 30 hours. But I feel catalogsearch full text is not mandatory to bring one product.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the cron to update on Schedule.

This way, thanks to the mview pattern, Magento will reindex only the entity_ids which need to be reindexed. (check `mview_state` and `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` tables)

You need to think about incremental update and not full update.

I have the same problem with my customer. It takes 8 minutes to full reindex by stores, I have 31 stores so ...

I am trying to reindex each store in parallel.

Did you find another solution ?